# Get the list of most seller combined products with its orders

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, products, sql, custom-reports

I want to get the most frequently sold product combinations, along with number of orders ( and Orders if possible).

I have customized the Magento tables for my warehouse activities and the sample code will be like this,

```
SELECT 
"Orders"."order_id",string_agg(pr.product_name:: character 
 varying, ',') as Product_names
 ,Count(Distinct "Orders"."order_id") as ordercount
FROM 
"data"."orders" AS "Orders"
LEFT JOIN  data.items i On i."order_id"="Orders"."order_id" 
LEFT join  data.products pr on pr."product_id"=i."product_id" 
 WHERE TO_CHAR("Orders"."created_at_order",'YYYY-MM-DD') 
BETWEEN '2019-02-01' AND '2019-04-30'
ORDER BY  "Orders"."order_id"
```

A sample of the expected result is shown below:
[image]

Let's say there are three products: P1,P2& P3.  I want to find the combination of products which is selling the most, along with their orders.

Also I want to exclude the parent-child items, meaning if a customer bought a set which contains three items(Parent), and if the combination product is shown as it's child  then it should be avoided.  Also the P1,P2&P3 which is the most selling combination product should count the orders if the P1,P2&P3 is included with other products also.

Is there a way to get this using SQL?  I'm using Postgresql, but it's free be if someone can help me with MySQL query or tables in Magento side.

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using?  Also, are you using [flat-product-tables](https://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/08/optimizing-magento-series-part-1-flat-tables-download-free-module/)?

Comment: @mtr.web I'm using Magento 1.9 now.No,Haven't used flat product tables yet .Is it contains the information necessary to manipulate or to get the most selled product combinations? It will be very helpful if you can guide me on this.